# Why do i get network error when i tried to access a database file(.mdf)?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i have used following simple LINQ2SQL query to access an .mdf database file on hard drive and display certain rows

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = @"D:\SE\MS\LINQ\LinqInAction\Data\NORTHWND.mdf";
        DataContext db = new DataContext(str);

       Table<Contact> contacts =   db.GetTable<Contact>();

       var x = from y in contacts
               select y;

       foreach (var item in x)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
       }
    }
}

[Table(Name = "Contacts")]
class Contact
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "ContactName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

But it gave me the following error
[image]

error message is

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

How do i fix this?

Comment: Configure the SQL Server to allow remote connections.

Comment: @dubstylee to config SQL server something new, how do i do it properly? and why i need to config SQL sever for this i only use .mdf file??

Comment: Is the .MDF an SQL Server database file?  Maybe SQL Server Compact?  Or SQL Server LocalDB?

Comment: @dubstylee yes its a sql server db file with northwind database. its my bad yes do need to configure server. but all the TCP/IP protocol are enabled but still no access. i have two firewall windows and zonealarm install on my comp. do i have to put exceptions on both?

Comment: I have found that firewalls do sometimes cause problems when initially configuring a database.  I would start by adding exceptions for SQL Server (port 1433 by default).  If that doesn't work, try temporarily disabling both firewalls and see if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: @dubstylee this is horrible even when i disable all firewalls and even the virus guard still the same error. Is there something wrong with my SQL server, is there away to default all configurations in SQL server, i use SQL server 2008R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you passed in for `new DataContext(str);` should be the name of the connection string configuration or the actual connection string. You can try with this instead:

```
string str = @"Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=D:\SE\MS\LINQ\LinqInAction\Data\NORTHWND.mdf;Database=NORTHWND;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
DataContext db = new DataContext(str);
```

or you can declare this connection string in app.config:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="nwDb" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=D:\SE\MS\LINQ\LinqInAction\Data\NORTHWND.mdf;Database=NORTHWND;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and use it in your code:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext("nwDb");
```

Comment: when i use the string (the first one) it gave this error Unable to open the physical file "D:\SE\MS\LINQ\LinqInAction\Data\NORTHWND.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
for the second one it gave me the original error i have posted : (

Comment: Maybe the file has been set to readonly. Can you uncheck the readonly box and try again. Perhaps you can also check the permission tab and set the permission to `everyone` with modify access..

Comment: i wasnt able to red from file but i was able to attach it from SQL SSMS then was able read from the app